# 404 with app 'Simple Api Call'

Tags: 2sxc

I installed dnn 9 locally with url http://dnndev.me/
Then I added the app 'Simple Api Call'. I get an 404-error for the url
http://dnndev.me/API/2sxc/app-api/SimpleDemoRequests/CurrentYear

Do I have to configure something specially?
Thanks for Help. 
Hajo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need 2sxc 8.9.1 or later, as DNN 9 changed the API routing and we only just implement that. See issue 1099 on https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/milestone/118?closed=1

Comment: BTW: in 2sxc 8.10.01 we''ll improve the routes to be a bit nicer. Meaning the old route .../app-api/...will still work, but then it would be best to change to .../app/[app-name]/api/...